# What should I do to make this rails app testable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, activesupport

I have an up to date rails application, using rails 3.2 with mongoid 2. I was unable to start testing by typing rake. The exception thrown is (sanitized):

```
rake test                                                                                                                         
/railsapp/app/models/image.rb:18:in `<class:Image>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /railsapp/app/models/image.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:359:in `require_or_load'
    from /gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:313:in `depend_on'
    from /gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `each'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:436:in `eager_load!'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:53:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /railsapp/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /railsapp/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `require'
    from /railsapp/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /railsapp/test/unit/post_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /railsapp/test/unit/post_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [/Users/janlimpens/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p...]>
```

I created a gist with the files that are of interest in the context:
https://gist.github.com/3989760

There is no test concerning the image model at all, there are no fixtures and the only test I have got is included into the gist, but it is not to blame, the error is thrown upon including test_helper.rb.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the tests start Rails loads up, as it does so it evaluates all of your models.

This includes the Image model, which apparently has a bug or typo on line 18.

Which would be this line:

```
:path => "#{APP_CONFIG['uploads_dir']}/:class/:id/:attachment/:style.:extension",
```

The only array notation here is:

```
APP_CONFIG['uploads_dir']
```

So, where is APP_CONFIG defined?  And why is it a nil?  These are the questions we must answer.

You might start by grepping your project for this string.

Comment: I use this in a lot of places. This comes from an initializer reading a yaml file into a global:  
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")[Rails.env]

Comment: But you seem to be correct in your assumption, one I remove the lines with the reference, I get exceptions only from the next file using this. Maybe at the time of the check these initializers have not yet run…

Comment: Do you have a section of your config.yml for the `test` environment?  Perhaps you forgot to define it, or its defined incorrectly.

Comment: No, it should load nicely - I assume it has to do with initialization order. I removed the inflicting string from the model and now all tests pass :)